# Why does $compile create multiple elements in ng-repeat?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why does $compile create multiple elements in ng-repeat?

HTML:

```
<li ng-repeat="action in actions" set-on-click function="{{action.function}}"><i class="{{action.class}}" aria-hidden="true"></i>{{action.text}}</li>
```

Directive:

```
directive('setOnClick', ['$compile', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: "A",
        link: function(scope, elm, attrs, ctrl)
        {
          console.log(attrs.function);  
          elm.attr("ng-click", attrs.function);
          elm.removeAttr("set-on-click");
          $compile(elm)(scope);
        }
      };
}]);
```

Im getting value for `$scope.actions` from the database which has 3 records. I had to use directive so as to bind `ng-click` to a function which im fetching from the database. Instead of getting 3 li items I'm getting 9. Each of the li is repeating itself thrice. Can someone please explain why? Is there a way to stop this duplicacy?

Comment: Try `priority: 1000`

Comment: where do i add the above code?

Comment: you can add it after restrict --->  [...]
        restrict: "A", priority: 1000, link [...]

Comment: Tried that..still not working..what does priority do?

Comment: Adding priority renders the li items correctly but the click function doesnt work

Comment: Added another anchor tag inside li for the link. Everything works fine now.

Comment: Have you tried ng-html-compile with UI-Grids? Two UI Grids are rendered for when I use ng-html-compile.